# E_SMS_USER_TABLEFILESDELETEDDIRECTLY error in U-SQL

Tags: runtime-error, azure-data-lake, u-sql

When we are trying to run a normal U-SQL job using azure data factory, which was executing perfectly fine earlier, suddenly failing with the below error for every table being referred in the U-SQL job.

> E_SMS_USER_TABLEFILESDELETEDDIRECTLY

But, I dont find any other jobs running at the same time. It is development environment and nobody is currently using it.

Please let us know, how we can fix the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is misleading. The issue was due to lack of permissions.

When I changed the account being used to connect to Azure Data Lake Analytics(ADLA), in the ADLA linked service in Azure data factory, I was able to successfully execute the job without issues.